# Getting error of handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@bf6ebe3

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, google-oauth, flutter-dependencies, google-signin

I have added Google sign-in feature in my app I am getting the below exception when pressing a sign-in button. I am using the Flutter framework.

```
handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@bf6ebe3
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in_android( 7807): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in_android( 7807): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Concurrent operations detected: signIn, disconnect
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in_android( 7807):   at io.flutter.plugins.googlesignin.GoogleSignInPlugin$Delegate.checkAndSetPendingOperation(GoogleSignInPlugin.java:327)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in_android( 7807):   at io.flutter.plugins.googlesignin.GoogleSignInPlugin$Delegate.checkAndSetPendingOperation(GoogleSignInPlugin.java:322)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in_android( 7807):   at io.flutter.plugins.googlesignin.GoogleSignInPlugin$Delegate.disconnect(GoogleSignInPlugin.java:461)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in_android( 7807):   at io.flutter.plugins.googlesignin.GoogleSignInPlugin.onMethodCall(GoogleSignInPlugin.java:184)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in_android( 7807):   at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:258)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in_android( 7807):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:295)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in_android( 7807):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$io-flutter-embedding-engine-dart-DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:322)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in_android( 7807):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:12)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in_android( 7807):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in_android( 7807):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in_android( 7807):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in_android( 7807):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7561)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in_android( 7807):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in_android( 7807):   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/google_sign_in_android( 7807):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:995)
I/Timeline( 7807): Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:548046764
```

Does anyone get the same error and resolved the issue please help me to resolve this. I have searched for the error not getting a solution. There is a GitHub issue which was closed without resolving.

Rechecked everything firebase settings, Oauth Consent, and configurations. Are there any steps that I missing please help.

Answer (score 0):

Here I am answering my question, I have resolved the issue.

There are multiple situations where you will get exceptions while implementing Google sign-in. In my case, the Google sign was calling multiple times.

First Scenario.

```
void handleGoogleSignIn() async {
      final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();
      final GoogleSignInAuthentication? googleAuth =
          await googleUser?.authentication;
      final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        accessToken: googleAuth?.accessToken,
        idToken: googleAuth?.idToken,
      ); }

//Disconnect function
googleSignIn.disconnect();
```

> Make sure that you are calling the above two functions only one time.

> This may occur while handling auto-login, checking the internet for logging out and auto-logout. You will be handling function in only one screen for the two or three processes handle it carefully.

Second Scenario.

There may be chances of getting an exception if you have not configured it in OAuthConsent with all the details in [[Google Console 1]](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis). Also, you need to make sure that you have added SHA1 to your project app.

[image]